# BroadcastReceiver not receiving

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have read the instructions and examples in SO questions, but still unable to implement a simple BroadcastReceiver, it simply does not receive anything, can someone kindly provide some advice on the following code?

tnx

My activity:

```
public class Receiver1Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(MyService.MY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(new MyReceiver(), filter);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

My receiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Log.i("MyReceiver", "onreceive");       
    }
}
```

My service, which sends the broadcast:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    public static final String MY_ACTION = "com.receiver1.myaction";
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(MY_ACTION);
        sendBroadcast(intent2);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

My manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.receiver1"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Receiver1Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".MyService"></service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you are starting a service with empty intent..I can assume you want to start your MyService to get a working code.

Comment: I'm kinda new to SO, I hope this gets better now, I've marked answers where missing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your service is even getting started? It looks like your just creating a blank intent and calling startService().

Your broadcastReceiver appears to be correct.

Comment: hmmm, actually, I now see that you are correct, the service does not reach onStartCommand, not sure why it got there earlier... I see in the logcat: "Unable to start service Intent [   ]: not found". why is that? why isn't an empty Intent enough? I don't have any particular request from the service - just that it should start...

Comment: ok got it, I called startService in the wrong way. I should create the intent like so:
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    startService(intent);

now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to [register your receiver in your AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html). Until you do that, the Android OS won't be able to find your BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Hello, Receiver has been dynamically declared in activity so need to declare it in manifest.

Comment: @iNan, good point. I think I'd still move it to the manifest, but that may be because I don't have a full mental picture of the lifecycle here. Is the activity guaranteed to have been created if his service is running?

Comment: If activity is active then activity can receive the broadcast, android wants all dynamically registered broadcasts to be be unregistered on termination of activity.

Comment: yes, of course, I'll do that in the "real" project, but I wrote this POC to eliminate bg noise and to be able to post sth here on SO for you guys :) so the issue is not the removal of the receivers, nor is it in its dynamic registration. The previous answer seems in the right direction, as the service was unable to start...